# C3P0 maxPoolSize exhausted

Tags: jdbc, database-connection, connection-pooling, c3p0

I have an application that uses C3P0 for connection pooling. It has been working fine for a long time, but recently i am getting the following exception while trying to hit the database.

```
com.amazon.carbonado.FetchException: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.TimeoutException: A client timed out while waiting to acquire a resource from com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@1bdc777 -- timeout at awaitAvailable()
```

Upon googling I found that this is due to maxPoolSize being exhausted. I increased the pool size from 25 to 100 to check if it is the reason. It was fixed temporarily, but some time later i am seeing the error again while attempting db connection (there werent any other db connection requests at that time). When i check the DB for active/inactive connections there is just 1 entry from the machine in v$session. Yet i am receiving this error. I donot understand where the connections are used ?

Can some one tell me why this could be happening. Also what does the maxPoolSize in C3P0 represent ? Is it that DB connections that can be checked out?

Also does the poolSize represent the actual dbConnections ?

Answer (score 4):

a few things. `com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.TimeoutException` indicates that you have set a `checkoutTimeout` and it has been exceeded. this usually happens because you've hit `maxPoolSize` and `Connections` are not being returned quickly, but not necessarily. if the value is very small, `Connection` acquisition on a not-maxed-out pool can provoke this.

that said, it sounds very much like what you have is a `Connection` leak leading to an exhausted pool. (to verify, unset `checkoutTimeout` and see if your application eventually hangs indefinitely, rather than throwing Exceptions.) if you are leaking Connections, you want to

1. be sure to use the reliable resource cleanup idiom in managing Connections -- [here](http://old.nabble.com/Re%3A-connection-are-not-returned-to-the-pool-p16088684.html), click "show rest of quote".
2. use [unreturnedConnectionTimeout](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#unreturnedConnectionTimeout) and [debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces) to track down and fix the Connection leak. see also [this discussion](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_to_debug_and_workaround_broken_clients).

good luck!